# docker-compose 1.6 "args" attribute on "build"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use the new "args" attribute to pass variable to Dockerfile build. But the yaml parser is not accepting the parameter.

```
ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
```

For version 2 of docker-compose.yml the requirements are docker-compose 1.6+ and docker-engine 1.10+ and I have both them installed.

This is part of my docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
 solr:
    build: ./solr
      args:
        solr_port: 8983
    volumes:
      - ./apps/solr-conf:/opt/solr/server/solr
    ports:
      - 8983:8983
```

The error refers to the "args" line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue here is that the `build` field should be specified as a path to the build context or as an object with the options, but not both. If you are going to use the `args` field, you have to specify the path of your build in the `context` field.

Check below how it should be:

```
version: '2'
services:
 solr:
    build: 
      context: ./solr
      args:
        solr_port: 8983
    volumes:
      - ./apps/solr-conf:/opt/solr/server/solr
    ports:
      - 8983:8983
```